# ASP.Net Hide Left Hand Menu On Home Page

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an asp.net website which is having a left hand menu added to it and have hit an issue as I have found that I am doing a lot of code duplication (which is bad I know). What I want is for the left hand menu to be added to my Site.Master file rather than me having to add it to every single page.

I can do this, but the left hand menu is then displayed on the "Home" page which I don't want so i was thinking that i need some sort of `IF` statement but I don't know how I can do this as I cant look at the URL as when the user hits the page its the standard naming (e.g. http://www.webaddress.co.uk/)

My left hand menu is a scrolling `nav-stacked` which is working fine so I will also need to add the JQuery for this to the Site.Master I think.

**Current HTML for my 'About Us' page**

```
<asp:Content ID="AboutBodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs" style="padding-left: 0px">
        <div class="follow-scroll">
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Session/pg1">Session</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="~/EmailPg">Email</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <h2><%: Title %>.</h2>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
        <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            var element = $('.follow-scroll'),
                originalY = element.offset().top;

            // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
            var topMargin = 75;

            // Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
            element.css('position', 'relative');

            $(window).on('scroll', function (event) {
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

                element.stop(false, false).animate({
                    top: scrollTop < originalY
                            ? 0
                            : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
                }, 300);
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

The HTML code below is what I thought of for my Site.Master but as I said it needs to not be displayed on the "Home Page".

```
    <div class="container body-content" style="padding-top: 25px">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">                            
                    <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs" style="padding-left: 0px">
                        <!-- 'IF' statement to go here so not displayed on Home page -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                            <li style="border-left: 1px solid lightgray"><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                            <li style="border-left: 1px solid lightgray"><a runat="server" href="~/Session/pg1">Session</a></li>
                            <li style="border-left: 1px solid lightgray"><a runat="server" href="~/EmailPg">Email</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" style="padding-right: 0px">
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using MVC, as this would be a pretty simple approach then.  Are you also using bootstrap?  Not sure if asp.net forms have sections as MVC do, but another option would be to create your left hand side menu as a control, and just load the control where necessary in your pages.

Comment: @akemp Yes I am using Bootstrap but no not using MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve all the issues, I added an `ID` and a `runat="server"` to the container for the menu, and then I could access it in the code behind:

```
div class="follow-scroll">
     <div ID="Sidebar" runat="server" class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs" style="padding-left: 0px">
          <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
               <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
               <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
               <li><a runat="server" href="~/Session/pg1">Session</a></li>
               <li><a runat="server" href="~/EmailPg">Email</a></li>
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then, in the codebehind for the master page, I can do something like:

#### C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var URL = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
    if(URL == "/default" || URL == "/default.aspx")
    {
        this.Sidebar.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

This uses [PathAndQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery.aspx) from the `HttpContext.Request.Url` property, which is a `Uri` object.

Then I was able to move my JQuery to my site.master file also

Comment: Does that about cover what you did? If/when you work out setting the active class (hint: you can set the CssClass property in the codebehind), you should probably edit that in as well.

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes it does but I now get the following error when I move my JQuery to the Site.Master for the scrolling of the sidebar "0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference" and if I leave the JQuery on the pages itself the menu doesn't scroll up/down when the user does. the JQuery can be found in my initial post

Comment: I would assume you have the jQuery reference at the bottom of the master page, but the script element as shown would proceed that in the rendered HTML. So, basically, jQuery wouldn't be loaded yet. I typically add a ContentPlaceholder called "ScriptsContent" to the bottom of the master page (after everything but the closing body tag), and then use that in the content page itself, just like MainContent.

Comment: @TiesonT. This an error on my part, I missed out my my wrapping `Div` which contained my `ID`. I have updated this in the HTML bit above. Everything now ok although I didn't use `.ToLower()` as for some reason it breaks it